# C#: AES error: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. Same key and everything, help

Tags: c#, aes, padding

I'm quite new to C# so please be patient with me. I know this question was asked a lot if times, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I'm saving some data and before writing it to a file I convert it to binary and store it in array, which I encrypt and then write to file. I encrypt data in chunks (32 bytes). In the same way I read data in chunks of 32 bytes and then decrypt that data and then this should repeat till the end of file. But when it comes to decryption the following error is thrown:

> **Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.**

I use the same key and iv (hardcoded just until I get it working)

Here is my encryption code, which works without problems:

```
        //result
        byte[] data = new byte[32];

        //setup encryption (AES)
        SymmetricAlgorithm aes = Aes.Create();
        byte[] key = { 145, 12, 32, 245, 98, 132, 98, 214, 6, 77, 131, 44, 221, 3, 9,50};
        byte[] iv = { 15, 122, 132, 5, 93, 198, 44, 31, 9, 39, 241, 49, 250, 188, 80, 7 };
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);

        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 1024, false);

        //prepare data to write (byte array 'data') ...

        //encrypt
               MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
               using (Stream c = new CryptoStream(m, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                   c.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
               data = m.ToArray();
               fStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

And here is my decryption code:

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, false);

            //setup encryption (AES)
            SymmetricAlgorithm aes = Aes.Create();
            byte[] key = { 145, 12, 32, 245, 98, 132, 98, 214, 6, 77, 131, 44, 221, 3, 9, 50 };
            byte[] iv = { 15, 122, 132, 5, 93, 198, 44, 31, 9, 39, 241, 49, 250, 188, 80, 7 };
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

            //result
            byte[] data = new byte[32];

            //loop for reading the whole file ...
            int len = fStream.Read(data, 0, 32);

            //decrypt
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                using (Stream c = new CryptoStream(m, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    c.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //The exception is thrown in this line                  
                data = m.ToArray();

                //using the decrypted data and then looping back to reading and decrypting...
```

I tried all I could think of (which is not much because I'm very new to cryptography), I searched everywhere and I couldn't find a solution to my problem. I also helped myself with the book *C# in a Nutshell* .

If anyone has ideas on why this could happen I'll be really thankful because I have no ideas.

Thank you for your time and answers.

EDIT:
It seems that the size of the encrypted data is 48 bytes (12 bytes more than the original). Why is that so? I thought that it only adds bytes if they are not a multiple of the block size (16 bytes, my data is 32 bytes). Is data always larger, and with constant increase (I need to know that in order to properly read and decrypt).

Note: I can't directly use other streams because I need to have control over the output format and I believe it is also safer and faster to encrypt in memory.

Comment: I think Ben is right here, can you check the file to see the output of the encrypted data (ie, is the binary file greater than 32 bytes?).  You'll want to read in the whole file and decrypt that.

Comment: other @Ben: 48 bytes is 16 bytes more than your input, not 12.  What prevents you from just using the length of the encrypted stream?  It should take only a couple extra bytes to save the length into whatever structure/wrapper envelope/pdu the encrypted data is embedded into.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 I checked the array after encryption and just before writing to file and it was 48 bytes large, yes, 16 more not 12 =). I can't because sometimes files can get really big and I'll need just one special chunk of data from a location that I'll calculate and thus I must be able to decrypt file in chunk-like fashion. @Ben Voigt well if it always (for same chunk size) creates the same "increment" in size then I can adapt but I find a waste of space as these things add up fast.

Comment: Makes sense.  I think I would turn padding off in that case, otherwise you will never know where to read from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your edit:

> EDIT: It seems that the size of the encrypted data is 48 bytes (12 bytes more than the original). Why is that so? I thought that it only adds bytes if they are not a multiple of the block size (16 bytes, my data is 32 bytes). Is data always larger, and with constant increase (I need to know that in order to properly read and decrypt).

If the encrypted data is 48 bytes, thats 16 bytes larger than your original array.  This makes sense because the algorithm with pad the data because the default is [PKCS7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode.aspx) (even if the size matches the block size, because it pads to the *next* multiple of the block-size).  If you wish to keep it exactly 32 bytes, just change the [Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding.aspx) to [None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode.aspx)

```
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem. So it always pads just till the next multiple of block-size? Because 'KeithS' posted :  _If your message isn't an even multiple of 16 bytes..._ Does it have to be even? btw it is just aes.Padding = ...

Comment: @Ben - It will pad to the next block size, so its always going to pad if its set.  I updated the code, thanks.  Glad this helped.

Comment: Well it seems I forgot to run this method and it seemed as thought it is working, but in fact it is not, still the same problem. I also again debugged and the data is still expanded to 48 bytes.

Comment: @Ben - Seems ok to me, when I copy what you have and set the Padding to None it generates a 32 byte output.  Make sure you set the padding before you create the encryptor.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be treating the length of the plaintext as the length of the ciphertext.  That's not a safe assumption.

<strike>Why are you copying between `FileStream` and `MemoryStream`, you can pass a `FileStream` directly to the encryptor/decryptor.</strike>

In PKCS7, there is a minimum of one padding byte (to store the number of padding bytes).  So the output size will be `Ceil16(input.Length + 1)`, or `(input.Length & ~15) + 1`.

Comment: Well, in his algorithm he's rolling his own byte array of exactly 32 bytes, which is an even multiple of the block size, so the ciphertext will in fact exactly match the input byte array. The problem is that to do so, he's done his own "padding", which is confusing the decryption step.

Comment: @Keith: And you're absolutely sure that the encryptor doesn't generate an extra header block or anything like that?

Comment: So if I would create a 31 bytes array I could pass with 32 bytes after decryption?

Comment: other @Ben: I predict that yes you can.

Answer (score 3):

The short of it is that AES encrypts messages in blocks of 16 bytes. If your message isn't an even multiple of 16 bytes, the algorithm needs to be a little different for the last block; specifically, the last block must be "padded" with a value known to the algorithm as a padding value (usually zero, sometimes something else like a space character value).

You're doing that yourself, by putting the data into a fixed-length byte array. You padded the data yourself, but the decrypter is now attempting to de-pad the last block and getting byte values it doesn't recognize as the padding that its encrypter counterpart would have added.

The key is not to pad the message. You can use the BitConverter class to cast byte arrays to and from IConvertible types (value types and strings), and then use that instead of rolling your own byte array. Then, when you decrypt, you can read from the decryption stream up to the ciphertext length, but don't expect there to be that many actual bytes in the decrypted result.

Answer (score 0):

while creating the object i did not set padding , therefore it was throwing error . After adding the padding value , it works completely fine.
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;