# Decrypting byte array with Rijndael - lost Bytes

Tags: c#

I am writing a encrypted (Rijndael) byte array in a .txt file.
When I read it out, I get a byte[48]. As soon as i decrypt it, I get a byte[32].

Why am I losing bytes here? If I write the result in the Console, it also cuts at a specific point.

```
static void ShowEntries()
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    path = path + @"\SafePass\";

    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(path + @"\crypt.txt");
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(file))
    {
        using (BinaryReader binary = new BinaryReader(memory))
        {
            byte[] result = binary.ReadBytes(file.Length);
            byte[] plainText = new byte[48];
            plainText = Decrypt(result);
            string SplainText = Converter(plainText);

            Console.WriteLine(SplainText);
        }
    }
}

static string Converter(byte[] data)
{            
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    return base64;
}

static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedByte)
{
    {
        string password = @"mykey123"; // Your Key Here

        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();

        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(mem,
            RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        cs.Write(encryptedByte, 0, encryptedByte.Length);

        byte[] cipherText = null;
        cipherText = mem.ToArray();

        cs.Close();
        return cipherText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add cs.Flush() before cs.Close()

Comment: Use `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllBytes` for encrypting, and use `File.ReadAllBytes` and `File.WriteAllText` for decrypting. I also see no use for that `BinaryReader` and the `MemoryStream` in `ShowEntries`. You already read the bytes with `File.ReadAllBytes`, just pass that variable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input data (i.e. what you're encrypting) is 32 bytes long, what's happening is that the encrypted data is being padded, which means that extra redundant information is added to the encrypted data.

[In .NET, the default padding mode for symmetrical algorithms like Rijndael](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding(v=vs.110).aspx) is PKCS #7.

I think that if you look at the extra data in the encrypted array all the extra values will be 16 (32 bytes input, next block is at 48, padding is the difference: 48-32=16).

Note that the padded bytes will be removed upon decryption, provided that the same padding mode is used for decryption as encryption. It's not going to affect your data.

But if you really want, you can set the padding mode to None, or one of the other values mentioned on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Here's a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080629/9456121) to a similar question that you can also refer to.

Comment: Actually my problem is that my input data is 48 bytes long and I don't get the full data back decrypted. The .txt read out is 48 bytes, but as soon as I decrpypt it, it is just 32 bytes left.

Comment: J€vÆ
PA‰8êÅš(/jÓòzÐ'
úE©Õ³ì$©Â¹½n™|e6’¨C—`ç)èô~Ì
/MŠ¨Ó»iz

Comment: I feel like some symbols in there cause problems.

Comment: No, I mean, can you post the C# code you've been using to encrypt the file please?